# Bootstrap 3 modal layout issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Rails 5 and Bootstrap 3 to build out an app. I want admins to be able to create and update users, using Bootstrap 3 modals.

The modal and the forms are working, but there is a layout issue. The modal body and footer seem to be running together. I have checked to ensure all the divs have been closed off and they appear to be, however the top div of the modal and its closing div don't seem to recognize each other...

I think the problem is with the modal id. It seems to work fine when I remove it, which leads me to believe that the problem is the Ruby in the id (see below).

The reason I am using the user.id in the modal id is to create unique modal id's as there are several users.

### Opening Modal Div with Ruby as part of the ID

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= "update_user#{user.id}" %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
...
</div>
```

### Full Modal Code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= "update_user#{user.id}" %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><text id="pv_text_grn">PATROL</text><text id="pv_text_gry">VAULT</text> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update <%= user.f_name %> <%= user.l_name %></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for(user, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :email, "Email" %><br />
                <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password %>
                <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => '* * * * * *' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => '* * * * * *' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :f_name, "First Name" %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :f_name, disabled: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :l_name, "Last Name" %>
                <%= f.text_field :l_name, disabled: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :primary_tel, "Telephone" %>
                <%= f.text_field :primary_tel, :class => 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :role_id %><br />
                <%= collection_select(:user, :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}) %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <%= f.submit "Update User", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Image Of Modal

[image]

You can see that the dividing line that should be at the footer is now for some reason at the top, just below the email label.

Comment: Your UI problem occurs because of `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` block of elements and wrap it outside the model block

Comment: just need to remove extra `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` in modal body and put `form_for`  outside the `modal-body` `modal-footer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the wrapping `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` tag.

I've also refactored the structure. You shouldn't have to wrap any inputs with `.col-xs-12`, this is default for inputs. You can wrap inputs in `.form-group` for bottom spacing.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= "update_user#{user.id}" %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><text id="pv_text_grn">PATROL</text><text id="pv_text_gry">VAULT</text> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update <%= user.f_name %> <%= user.l_name %></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for(user, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email, "Email" %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password %>
                <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => '* * * * * *' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => '* * * * * *' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :f_name, "First Name" %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :f_name, disabled: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :l_name, "Last Name" %>
                <%= f.text_field :l_name, disabled: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :primary_tel, "Telephone" %>
            <%= f.text_field :primary_tel, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :role_id %><br />
                <%= collection_select(:user, :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}) %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit "Update User", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you should consider using `dom_id` for your tag ids. It will prefix the id with the correct verb based on if the object. (edit or new) And follows the rails naming convention pattern.

```
# Update
dom_id(Post.find(45), :edit) # => "edit_post_45"
dom_id(Post.new, :custom)    # => "custom_post"
# New
dom_id(Post.find(45))       # => "post_45"
dom_id(Post.new)            # => "new_post"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html

You can use it with `content_tag` or embed in the html tag.

```
<%= content_tag :div, id: dom_id(user) do %>...<% end %>
<div id="<%= dom_id user %>">...</div>
```

PS: There is also `dom_class`.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to create and fix this issue.

I was using this code:

```
<form method="post" action="/api/foo">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" class="changed" name="key_str" value="{{ machine.key_str }}"/>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label>Text input 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row col-lg-12">
      <label>Checkbox</label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

which created this modal:

[image: Incorrect modal]

Moving the `row` class to its own `<div>` corrected the problem:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <label>Checkbox</label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Correct modal]